# How to split a file and compress directly?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, gzip

I've a 100GB file and I want to split into 100 of 1GB file each (by line break)

e.g.

```
split --bytes=1024M /path/to/input /path/to/output
```

For the 100 files generated, I want to apply gzip/zip to each of these files.

Is it possible to use a single command?

Comment: For up to 1GB per file (less if the next line would put it over) use `--line-bytes=1024M`.

Answer (score 41):

Use "--filter":

`split --bytes=1024M --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz' /path/to/input /path/to/output`

Comment: this does not twork for me, keeps overwriting the same file as $FILE is not defined and does not even write in to the des folder.

Comment: my mistake, needs single quotes to get $FILE replaced, my big mistake, apologies and thanks for the help: this final command worked for me to save fastq data that comes in blocks of 4 lines: 'zcat ERR3152365.fastq.gz | split -a 3 -d -l 1200000 --numeric-suffixes --filter='pigz -p 8 > $FILE.fq.gz' - splitout/part_'

Comment: Exactly what I needed to compress/download a 20G text file in manageable chunks.

Comment: Filter is a great option with the GNU version of split.  Unfortunately, its not available on the BSD version shipped with Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner using a conditional is as close as you can come.

```
cd /path/to/output && split --bytes=1024M /path/to/input/filename && gzip x*
```

`gzip` will only run if `split` is successful because of the conditional `&&` which is also between the `cd` and `split` making sure the `cd` is successful, too.. Note that `split` and `gzip` output to the current directory instead of having the ability to specify the output directory. You can make the directory, if needed:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/output && cd /path/to/output && split --bytes=1024M /path/to/input/filename && gzip x*
```

To put it all back together:

```
gunzip /path/to/files/x* && cat /path/to/files/x* > /path/to/dest/filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this command with `-d` option allows you to generate numeric sufixes.

```
split -d -b 2048m "myDump.dmp" "myDump.dmp.part-" && gzip myDump.dmp.part*
```

Files generated:

```
    myDump.dmp.part-00
    myDump.dmp.part-01
    myDump.dmp.part-02
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A bash function to compress on the fly with pigz

```
function splitreads(){

# add this function to your .bashrc or alike
# split large compressed read files into chunks of fixed size
# suffix is a three digit counter starting with 000
# take compressed input and compress output with pigz
# keeps the read-in-pair suffix in outputs
# requires pigz installed or modification to use gzip

usage="# splitreads <reads.fastq.gz> <reads per chunk; default 10000000>\n";
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo;
        echo ${usage};
        return;
    fi;

# threads for pigz (adapt to your needs)
thr=8

input=$1

# extract prefix and read number in pair
# this code is adapted to paired reads
base=$(basename ${input%.f*.gz})
pref=$(basename ${input%_?.f*.gz})
readn="${base#"${base%%_*}"}"

# 10M reads (4 lines each)
binsize=$((${2:-10000000}*4))

# split in bins of ${binsize}
echo "# splitting ${input} in chuncks of $((${binsize}/4)) reads"

cmd="zcat ${input} \
  | split \
    -a 3 \
    -d \
    -l ${binsize} \
    --numeric-suffixes \
    --additional-suffix ${readn} \
    --filter='pigz -p ${thr} > \$FILE.fq.gz' \
    - ${pref}_"

echo "# ${cmd}"
eval ${cmd}
}
```